# Functionality Limitations with Experience Sites: Screen Flows+?

Tags: experience-cloud, screen-flow, community-cloud

Are there any **limitations** to using Screen Flows on an **Experience Site** (assuming our Site users are given the highest-level site license, which I'm assuming is Partner Community)?

Better yet, is there a public resource that lists the known functional limitations of Sites, as opposed to the internal application (from a config and/or end-user experience perspective)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public resource about any limitations as there are no limitations for flow in the Experience Builder Site.

One important thing is to make sure you use Experience Builder and not classic VF to build your Site. This way you have lightning runtime.

> Lightning runtime is needed for most of the out-of-box screen flow components.

However, there are a couple of important links with some useful info to bear in mind

- [Lightning Component Considerations with flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_salesforce_features_lc.htm&type=5)
- [Flow distribution in Experience Cloud Site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_external_community.htm&type=5)